# Script is getting executed before I press button

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm stuck in this code this is a coursera assignment on angularjs. I'm beginner in angular js and new to stackoverflow. This is a code about to find how much a person should it. It counts the number of items and then show the result. Items are seperated by ','.

```js
(function () {
  'use strict';
  angular.module('LunchCheck', [])
  .controller('LunchCheckController', LunchCheckController);

  LunchCheckController.$inject = ['$scope'];

  function LunchCheckController($scope) {
    //$scope.msg="";
    //console.log($scope.calculate);
    $scope.calculate="";
    $scope.check = Checker($scope);



  }

  function Checker(string) {
    var str = string.calculate;
    console.log(str);
    var str1 = str.split(',');
    var temp = str1.length;
    console.log(temp);

    string.msg=message(string,temp);
    }
    function message(string,temp) {
      if(temp > 3) {
        return "Too Much!";
   
    }
    else if (temp==0) {
      return "Aren`t you hungry??";
      
    }
    else {
      return "Enjoy";
      //console.log('Enjoy');
    }
    }


})();
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <title>Lunch Checker</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <!--<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/bootstrap.min.css">-->
    <style>
      .message { font-size: 1.3em; font-weight: bold; }
    </style>
    <script src="angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
  </head>
<body ng-app="LunchCheck">
   <div class="container" ng-controller="LunchCheckController">
     <h1>Lunch Checker</h1>

         <div class="form-group">
             <input id="lunch-menu" type="text"
             placeholder="list comma separated dishes you usually have for lunch"
             class="form-control" ng-model="calculate">
         </div>
         <div class="form-group">
             <button class="btn btn-default" ng-click="check();">Check If Too Much</button>
         </div>
         <div class="form-group message">
           <!-- Your message can go here. -->
           {{msg}}
         </div>
   </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Here javascript function is getting executed before I enter any input. I want it to execute after I enter a input. Please help.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: `.check = Checker($scope);` because you are executing it

Comment: Instead you declare a new function  `$scope.check = function(){ Checker($scope); }` that executes when clicked. Or reference an existing function: `$scope.check = Checker;`  But you execute a function by using its name followed by parentheses - yes, even during variable assignment like`$scope.check = Checker($scope);` it will be called immediately and $scope.check will be assigned any returned value.

Comment: Thanks ippi and Patrick! Problem solved.